# ES6 and sequelize-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, babeljs

My question is how to run `sequelize` migrations/seeds that written in ES6 ?

I tried with `babel-node`, but getting weird error

Command

```
node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel-node.js node_modules/sequelize-cli/bin/sequelize  db:seed
```

Error

```
node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel-node.js: line 1: /Applications: is a directory
node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel-node.js: line 3: /Applications: is a directory
node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel-node.js: line 4: 127.0.0.1: command not found
node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel-node.js: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel-node.js: line 5: ` * when found, before invoking the "real" _babel-node(1) executable.'
```

Comment: Can you provide example of your ES6 migrations/seeds?

Answer (score 9):

Actually, if I got the question, you want to use es6 with `sequelize`.

According to the official docs you just have to do this easy steps
firstly, Install the babel dependencies especially `@babel\register`

`npm install @babel\register`

secondly, Create a `.sequelizerc` at the root of the project and add the following

```
 require("@babel\register");

    const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.json'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
}
```

After doing the above you can start using sequelize with es6 syntax

for further reading you can visit the official docs
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/migrations.html#using-babel

Remember to have fun

Comment: It looks like your 3rd step got cut off. `use the sequelize-cli with e`. What is `e`?

Comment: @hafichuk thanks for spotting that, if you have further inquiry, just add a comment and I will try to help you further

Comment: @DanielCharlesMwangila i didn't get the third step. Could you explain little bit

Comment: @AjishVNair sorry for the late reply, I added the third to just indicate that you can start using all the sequelize-cli commands like creating migration and models. sorry if its misleading

Comment: @DanielCharlesMwangila i was getting this error while using require("@babel\register");                                                                                             Error reading "config/migration_config.js". Error: Error: [BABEL] /home/neoito/projects/Accounting/house-server/accounts-server/config/migration_config.js: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-beta.41", but was loaded with "7.0.0-beta.3". You'll need to update your @babel/core version. (While processing: "/home/neoito/projects/Accounting/house-server/accounts-server/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

Comment: @AjishVNair can you try using

`npm i --save-dev babel-register`

`require("babel-register");

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.json'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
}`

Answer (score 5):

Try this configuration: https://gist.github.com/andrewmunro/030f0bf62453239c495b0347c8cd1247.

It's working for me.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for your comment. I'm following the steps in the repo you shared, but, in the config.js file in the line
import config from 'my/app/config';
i don not know what should i import here. Can you share it with me please, i´ll appreciate your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Google led me here, and this still requires configuration.
But found a solution which even lets you write migrations scripts using ES6 syntax.

Reference: https://gist.github.com/elawad/c0af86ea37629ad0538c2b974b4ea0c1